# Use Case Diagram logic

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case-diagram

I'm currently studying for my final exams, and I'm trying to get my head around the use case diagrams. I usually can do the diagrams without problems, but i have been stuck on this one specifically which im not sure if it is correct or not.

Here are the use cases:

(A) All users of the System can browse and search for titles

(B) Users include Borrowers and Librarians

(C) A borrower can checkout and return items. If during check out it turns out that the title is not available (all copies have been borrowed) then the borrower can reserve the title for the future

(D) When the title becomes available the borrower is notified by e-mail

(E) A borrower can browse the list of reservations and cancel them

(F) A librarian can register new borrowers and add new titles

[image: User Case 1]

[image: Use case 2]

My doubts are:

- Does the borrower need to interact with the "Register new Borrower" use case? Considering a user would need to register, the librarian would also need to interact with the system, so I assume both  need to be linked?
- when the title becomes available, from which use case should it come?

As you can see in the first picture, the use case Title Available comes as a new use case from the Title not Available use case, and in the second picture, I did it as an extend from Check out item.

Which one of this diagrams would represent best the use case descriptions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will just give you some thoughts since SO is basically no homework correction place.

- > (B) Users include Borrowers and Librarians

  That means there must be a general Actor `User` from which `Borrowers` and `Librarians` inherit. And you would connect `User` to UC for both og the others.
- > (F) A librarian can register new borrowers and add new titles

  Thats modeled wrongly in both diagrams. Only `Librarian` must be associated.
- There can't be Associations between UCs (like in your #1). However,
- `Title not available` is no UC but a sequence of (alternative) steps in the UC `Check out item`. There are more "UCs" bubbles which are no UCs at all. A UC is about added value. Read Bittner/Spence (but you probably have to hurry then).

Most of your UCs are ok, though.

Comment: Thanks for you help, although this is not homework. This are previous years exams which I am redoing to get more familiar with UML. Since my lecturer does not provide any solutions of previous years exams, I have no way of knowing If they are correct or not other than asking someonelse who might know the subject better

Comment: One never knows. There are quite some homeworks appearing here. So if you got time I strongly recommend reading Bittner/Spence. That's (to me) by far the best read about UCs. Once reading it I had a good idea what UCs are all about. It took me a couple of years though to lift the curtain (more or less) completely.